# How to insert angular's ui-sref into the text of a link?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an app that uses AngularJS.
In on of my views, I have something that looks like this:

```
<span>My URL: <a ui-sref="mystate({ arg1_name: 'arg1_val', arg2_name: 'arg2_val'})">XXX</a></span>
```

This works perfectly as I expect it to. No problems.

However, I would like to replace ***XXX*** with the actual URL that is in the `<a>` tag.
How do I do that? simply replacing XXX with the entire `ui-sref` expression doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$state.href()](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_href) method. `ui-sref` directive updates `href` internally using this.

Answer by PSL has two correct approaches for this.

If using

`{{$state.href('mystate', { arg1_name: 'arg1_val', arg2_name: 'arg2_val'})}}`

`$state` is injected into scope using `$scope.$state = $state`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68388/discussion-between-aniket-sinha-and-psl).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the router version 0.2.0 there is a new method to get the url from the state configuration. You can use [`$state.href(stateOrName [, params] [, options])`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statehrefstateorname--params--options) for that. Provided you place `$state` instance on the scope, you can do:

```
<span><a 
   ui-sref="mystate({ arg1_name: 'arg1_val', arg2_name: 'arg2_val'})">
   {{$state.href('mystate', { arg1_name: 'arg1_val', arg2_name: 'arg2_val'})}}
</a></span>
```

The options can be:-

1) lossy Boolean (default true) If true, and if there is no url associated with the state provided in the first parameter, then the constructed href url will be built from the first navigable ancestor (aka ancestor with a valid url).

2) inherit Boolean (default false) If true will inherit url parameters from current url.

3) relative stateObject (default $state.$current), When transitioning with relative path (e.g '^'), defines which state to be relative from.

4) absolute Boolean (default false) If true will generate an absolute url, e.g. "http://www.example.com/fullurl".

You wont be able to access injected `$state` in your view unless you associate it to the scope or controller instance (if you are using controller As). So you can add a scope method on your controller.

```
 $scope.getUrl = function(state, params){
     return $state.href(state, params, anyOptions);
 }
```

and in your view:-

```
{{getUrl('mystate', { arg1_name: 'arg1_val', arg2_name: 'arg2_val'})}}
```

and access it on the view by calling `getUrl` function. If you want this functionality across controllers you could either move it to a utilityService function or place the utility method on the rootScope in the run block so that any child scopes will have access to it (Though for unit testing you may need to mock it based on your set up).

*Remember to inject `$state`.*

Comment: How can I tell which version of router I'm using? I tried your solution `$state.href('mystate', { arg1_name: 'arg1_val', arg2_name: 'arg2_val'})` and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Open up the angular ui route file. Version will be on the top

Comment: @SaqibAli are u placing `$state` on the scope to be able to access it in the view? href comes along with ui-sref so yours has to be the right version. Also remember to place it between `{{` `}}` and you need to inject $state. Read my complete answer.

Comment: @SaqibAli What is the issue then.? Do you have $state injected?